# Using the last item in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, image, content-management-system, gallery

Hello I am using [Cockpit CMS](http://getcockpit.com/) as the backend for a new project, and I have set my `index.php` to have a background image.

Now I want the user to be able to change the images in a "gallery" without deleting the other images and I want to load up the last image in the "gallery".

Here is the Cockpit Galleries [documentation](http://getcockpit.com/docs#!modules/galleries).

I can do this with this:

```
<?php foreach(gallery('Backgrounds') as $images): ?>

    <?php thumbnail($images["path"]) ?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

however this loads all the images and is really slow and inefficient, what I want to do is load up the images into an array and use the last image, this is what I have so far:

```
<?php $images = cockpit("galleries")->gallery('Backgrounds'); ?>

<?php thumbnail(end($images["path"])) ?>
```

Update:

Checked PHP log am receiving this error:

```
PHP Warning:  end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Users/username/Developer/Beardedweb/index.php on line 10
```

Sorry not very PHP proficient.

Cheers,
Otis Wright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. First you have to get the last element of the array and *then* get it's value.

```
<?php 
$img = end($images);
thumbnail($img["path"]);
?>
```

Comment: A less elegant way would be `$images[count($images) - 1]['path']`, but the `end()` option is the most reliable way to do it.